# Diagnosing Freezing Applications

Tags: networking, proxy

Running Ubuntu 19.10, I am having issues with Discord running on my system. What seems to happen is the application hangs, and I must close the executable and re-open. Notably, it seems to occur whenever an 'event' (message or screen change) occurs. When it hangs, I note the following:

```
discord:31123): libnotify-WARNING **: 21:27:36.572: Failed to connect to proxy
```

There is no settings within the desktop application for proxy settings that I could locate. I have had a look at the console upon load and can see an initial connection:

```
[GatewaySocket] [CONNECTED] wss://gateway.discord.gg/?encoding=etf&v=6&compress=zlib-stream in 183 ms
```

To work around this, I have been using the web interface with no issue. To check the settings, I ran the following:

```
╭─mn@loopback ~ 
╰─$ echo "$http_proxy" 

╭─mn@loopback ~ 
╰─$ echo "$https_proxy"

╭─mn@loopback ~ 
╰─$ echo "$ftp_proxy"  

╭─mn@loopback ~ 
╰─$ echo "$all_proxy"
```

My system still uses `firewalld` and not `ufw`, but I myself have made no changes to the configuration of the policies. Running the latest version of Discord. Is this something I should take up with the developers, or is there more diagnostics I can do locally? (Apart from Wireshark captures and other network tests)

```
Stable 58583 (b7763a5)
Host 0.0.10
Linux 64-Bit (5.3.0-46-Generic)
```

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is EOL and thus off-topic here unless your question is specific to seeking help moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.

Comment: I find it odd you cannot comment on *general diagnostics*, as the OS version was simply added for context. Never the less, I am on Ubuntu 19.10 *not* 19.04, which has Standard Support according to the release cycle. Care to help?

Answer (score 2):

Recently bumped into similar issue ([Hotkeys respond lag, updating notification area player lags, Wi-Fi icon update slow, etc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1301972/hotkeys-respond-lag-updating-notification-area-player-lags-wi-fi-icon-update-s)), looks like you need to run
`/usr/lib/notification-daemon/notification-daemon`
because for some reason it's not launching automatically.

The error is caused by `libnotify` trying to connect, see e.g.
https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/24052

In my case, I was running Unity, and I ran `unity-settings-daemon --debug -r` to diagnose; it was getting stuck emitting this message every time:

> (unity-settings-daemon:3474363): libnotify-WARNING **: 01:12:15.195: Failed to connect to proxy