# Hotkeys respond lag, updating notification area player lags, Wi-Fi icon update slow, etc

Tags: unity, notification-area

After upgrade of my latest Ubuntu 20.04 I'm getting all kinds of weird delays when using brightness/volume hotkeys; or when using app that updates the system tray (especially player in volume menu popup).
List of symptoms:

- Spotify - switching songs takes minutes, tray information is not in
  sync with current song
- Volume, brightness - after keys are pressed,    updates happen in
  discrete steps with ~15 seconds between each other
- Mattermost - application keeps getting greyed out and "Busy", never
  recovers (probably when it updates systray).
- Rhythmbox - same behavior as Spotify but also application is greyed
  out as "Busy", recovers after ~15 seconds.
- Wi-Fi icon - updates to Wi-Fi icon happen with huge delays, switching
  networks happens with a delay.

I got several reports of iBus crashing but otherwise system was completely stable before upgrade.

Comment: Found https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-settings-daemon/+bug/1746277

Comment: Found the reason, my answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1306596